# Can I get the Absolution trophy via level select if I didn't start on Professional difficulty?

Tags: achievements, hitman-absolution

The last trophy I need for Hitman Absolution is the golden "Absolution" trophy, rewarded for completing the game on any Professional difficulty.

Difficulty's are divided in two groups:

- Enhanced

  - Easy
  - Normal
- Professional

  - Hard
  - Expert
  - Purist

I started on Normal difficulty for like 4 levels and switched to Hard because I was aware of the trophy. The trophy didn't pop after I completed the game (as expected).

My question is: Can I `level select` to do the missions I did on normal or do I need to start all over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

According to [PS3Trophies.org trophy guide & roadmap](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/hitman-absolution/180553-hitman-absolution-trophy-guide-roadmap.html), completing levels on Hard through level select is enough, see the description for the *Absolution* trophy (emphasis mine):

> Note: If you didn't do your first playthrough on this difficulty, you can get the trophy via new story **or level select**.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will get my platinum tonight if this works :)